# How to create tmux window without attaching to the session?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to be able to create a new tmux window(tab) in a session called 'scratch' running a custom command (ie. 'ping www.google.com') without attaching to the session. I'd also like 'scratch' to be created if it doesn't exist.

How would the shell script be written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plagiarized and altered a bit from [another of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628034/how-can-i-create-multiple-tmux-sessions-containing-windows-from-command-line/54637889#54637889), here's an example:

```
TMUX_SESSION_NAME='scratch'
tmux new-session -d -s $TMUX_SESSION_NAME >/dev/null
tmux new-window -t $TMUX_SESSION_NAME
tmux send-keys -t $TMUX_SESSION_NAME:1.0 'ping www.google.com' Enter
```

More info (my configuration):

Here's what I use to start my tmux sessions. The argument to the function would be the name of the session you want to create.

If this does not answer your question, please comment and edit your question to that it is more clear to me.

```
tmuxstart() {
    tmux new-session -d -s $1 >/dev/null
    tmux rename-window -t $1:0 'main'
    tmux splitw -v -p 10 -t $1:0.0
    tmux splitw -h -p 80 -t $1:0.1
    #required; otherwise pane numbering is bs
    tmux select-pane -t $1:0.0
    tmux splitw -h -p 5 -t $1:0.0
    tmux send-keys -t $1:0.2 'sudo htop' Enter
    tmux send-keys -t $1:0.1 'tmux clock -t $1:0.1' Enter
    tmux select-pane -t $1:0.0
    tmux new-window -t $1
    tmux rename-window -t $1:1 'second'
    tmux splitw -v -p 10 -t $1:1.0
    tmux splitw -h -p 80 -t $1:1.1
    tmux select-pane -t $1:1.0
    tmux splitw -h -p 5 -t $1:1.0
    tmux clock -t $1:1.1
    tmux new-window -t $1
    tmux rename-window -t $1:2 'scratch'
    tmux splitw -v -p 10 -t $1:2.0
    tmux select-pane -t $1:2.0
    tmux splitw -h -p 5 -t $1:2.0
    tmux clock -t $1:2.1
    tmux select-window -t $1:0.0
    tmux a -t $1
}
```